# Creating a vector in MATLAB with a pattern

Tags: math, matlab, vector

How do I create a vector like this:

```
a = [a_1;a_2;...,a_n]; 
aNew = [a;a.^2;a.^3;...;a.^T].
```

Is it possible to create aNew without a loop?

Answer (score 7):

So you want different powers of a, all strung out into a vector? I would create an array, where each column of the array is a different power of a. Then string it out into a vector. Something like this...

```
aNew = bsxfun(@power,a,1:T);
aNew = aNew(:);
```

This does what you want, in a simple, efficient way. bsxfun is a more efficient way of writing the expansion than are other methods, such as repmat, ndgrid and meshgrid.

The code I wrote does assume that a is a column vector, as you have constructed it.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: Thanks woodchips, also Happy New Year ;)

Comment: Season's Greetings -- This is very nice. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to use `meshgrid` to create two arrays of size `n x T`:

```
[n_mesh, t_mesh] = meshgrid(a, 1:T);
```

Now n_mesh is an array where each row is a duplicate of `a`, and t_mesh  is an array where each column is `1:T`.

Now you can use an element-wise operation on them to create what you need:

```
aNew = n_mesh .^ t_mesh;
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan,

pretty cool solution.

Greets and Happy New Year